# Not waiting for input java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a program that is supposed to take an integer input, output some characters based on the input, and then prompt to run the program again. E.g.

```
Please enter an integer --> 3

x

xx

xxx

xx

x

Do you want to run again?
```

This is the code for my program:

```
import java.util.*;
public class CMIS242Assignment1Stars 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String again;

       do //start of "run again" loop
        {
            System.out.print("Input a positive integer and press [ENTER]--> ");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            if (input.hasNextInt()) // check if input is parsable to an int
            {        
                int num = Integer.parseInt(input.next());

                if (num <= 0) //check if num is positive
                {
                    System.out.println(num + " is not a positive integer. Using +" + (num*-1) + " instead.");
                    num = num *= -1;
                }    
                String stars = new String(new char[num]).replace("\0", "*"); // create a string of '*' of length 'num'
                int forNum = num * 2;
                int flip = 0;

                for (int x = 0; x <= forNum ; x++)
                {
                    System.out.println(stars.substring(0,stars.length() - num)); //create substrings of variable length from 'stars'

                    if(num <= 0)
                    {
                        flip = 1;
                    }

                    if(flip == 0)
                    {
                        num--;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        num++;
                    }
                }
            }           
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("ERROR: Please input a positive integer!");//error message if a non-integer is entered
            }

            System.out.print("Would you like to run again? [Yes / No] ");
            again = input.next();     
        }
        while(again.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || again.equalsIgnoreCase("y")); // end of "run again" loop

        System.out.print("Good Bye!"); //exit message        
    }
}
```

I think the problem is with the code that ensures a correct input. The program works perfectly if an int or negative int is input but the program does not wait for the "run again" prompt when a non-int is entered as input. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your logic a little bit.

The easiest solution for you would be to fix your else statement.

```
else 
{
  //Move scanner position.
  String badInput = input.next();
  System.out.println("ERROR: Please input a positive integer!");//error message if a non-integer is entered
}
```

You check if `input.hasNextInt()` but it does not, the console has something that is  not an integer. The `hasNextInt()` method doesn't actually move the scanner position when you use `hasNextInt()`. To solve this issue we use a `input.next()` in the else statement.

Comment: The `badInput`, in the original code, is being assigned to `again`, which causes unexpected results.

Comment: I don't see anything named badInput in the original code. What do you mean? I do not understand.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. The _bad_ `String` being collected from the input, that you assign to `badInput`, is being (instead) assigned to the variable `again`, in the original code. The original code lacks the step of collecting `badInput`, that you suggest, which is correct.

Comment: Yes I am and so are you. :P I have added the explaination in the answer itself. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks the program works great now!